# Error while reading rosbag file using Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, ros

I am new to both Qt Creator and C++ and I want to make a GUI using Qt Creator to display data given from a rosbag. But I have a problem to import the rosbag into Qt. I tested the code given from [Rosbag reader in qtcreator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42764610/rosbag-reader-in-qtcreator) but get the error:

```
error: cannot find -ltf2_ros
error: cannot find -lrospack
error: cannot find -lroslib
error: cannot find -lroscpp
error: cannot find -lrosconsole_bridge
error: cannot find -lrosbag_storage
error: cannot find -lrosbag
```

How do I add those libraries?

Comment: Have you installed the libraries on your OS?

Comment: what is your OS?

Comment: Do you use caktin or qmake ? Can you paste your cmake lists ?

Comment: I have ubuntu 16.04. No I can not find those libaries, can you help me?

Comment: Did you install ros ?

Comment: Yes I have but i do not know how to add new libaries or how to find them. I am a real noobie in this area :p

Comment: First thing to do when we use ROS, is to follow these tutorials : http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials (and in particular the 3, 4, and 11).

You can check libraries are installed in the following folder /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/ (if you use ros-kinetic which is the default on ubuntu)

Comment: I made it work now. I did not give the right path for the libraries so thank you. I will definitely check out those tutorials as well.

Comment: again, do not use qmake ! It may appear easiest for you now, but you will face some very hard to solve problem later. Ros does not support QMake. Check tutorials, and learn catkin.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will have more pertinent responses on the ROS answers website. But I can start to answer to your question.

First thing to do when you start using ROS, is to follow these tutorials : http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials (and in particular the 3, 4, and 11).

You can check libraries are installed in the following folder /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/ (if you use ros-kinetic which is the default on ubuntu 16.04).

Then, when you develop a ROS node, do not use Qmake, use catkin and cmake.

A minimal CMake to use catkin and QT will look like this :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12)
project(librosqt)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED roscpp)
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
find_package(Qt5Core)

catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS include
  LIBRARIES librosqt
  CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp
)

include_directories(include ${Qt5Core_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})


add_library(librosqt src/QRosCallBackQueue.cpp include/librosqt/QRosCallBackQueue.h)

add_executable(test_rosqt_node test/main.cpp test/TestObject.cpp)

target_link_libraries(test_rosqt_node 
   librosqt
   ${catkin_LIBRARIES} Qt5::Core
)

install(TARGETS librosqt
  ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
  LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
  RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
)

install(DIRECTORY include/${PROJECT_NAME}/
  DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DESTINATION}
  FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.h"
  PATTERN ".svn" EXCLUDE
)
```

Then, if you use catkin. You will have a package.xml in which you will list all your dependendecies (QT, tf2 etc ...). Then before building your ros workspace you can use rodeps install , and this tool will install all your libraries. (see the doc [here](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/rosdep)).

Another important thing to note : Don't forget *to source* !!!!
Before building your node, you will have to source the following files :
`/opt/ros/kinetic|lunar/setup.bash` and `your_workspace_home/devel/setup.bash`.

If you want to build in QTCreator (with the build button), be sure that qtcreator was launched in a sourced environment.

Comment: According to what I see in the question the problem is that it lacks to install the libraries. And seeing your answer, this does not respond to the OP.

Comment: If he use catkin, as I suggest, and rosdeps, library will be automatically installed when he will build.

Comment: Good point, I recommend that you put it in your answer to remove the downvote.